# ¿Cómo puedo saber el crecimiento de los tablespace en un determinado tiempo?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-12c

Quisiera saber si existe una consulta que me permita ver el crecimiento que hubo de los tablespace por 
un determinado tiempo (ya sea por dia, semana, mes o año), también si existe alguna consulta que me permita ver los cambios que han generado crecimiento sobre la base de datos.

Lo que hago para poder ver el tamaño actual de los tablespace es el siguiente:

```
SELECT  df.tablespace_name "Tablespace",
   df.bytes / (1024 * 1024) "Size (MB)",
   SUM(fs.bytes) / (1024 * 1024) "Free (MB)",
   Nvl(Round(SUM(fs.bytes) * 100 / df.bytes),1) "% Free",
   Round((df.bytes - SUM(fs.bytes)) * 100 / df.bytes) "% Used"
FROM dba_free_space fs,
   (SELECT tablespace_name,SUM(bytes) bytes
      FROM dba_data_files
     GROUP BY tablespace_name) df
WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name
GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,df.bytes
UNION ALL
SELECT df.tablespace_name tspace,
   fs.bytes / (1024 * 1024),
   SUM(df.bytes_free) / (1024 * 1024),
   Nvl(Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_used) * 100 / fs.bytes), 1),
   Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_free) * 100 / fs.bytes)
FROM dba_temp_files fs,
   (SELECT tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used
      FROM v$temp_space_header
     GROUP BY tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used) df
WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name
GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,fs.bytes,df.bytes_free,df.bytes_used
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```